# nestjs-oidc-provider get route 404 after add findAccount in configuration

Tags: typescript, nestjs, openid-connect

so i want added findAccount to return user data, after i add method findAccount i got route 404 /auth/:uid

this my configuration

```
getConfiguration(): OidcConfiguration {
    return {
      findAccount(ctx, sub, token) {
        console.log(ctx);
        return this.account.findAccount(ctx, sub, token);
      },
    };
  }
```

and this my findAccount Method

```
  findAccount(
    ctx: KoaContextWithOIDC,
    sub: string,
    token?: any,
  ): Promise<Account> {
    console.log('ctx', ctx, 'sub:', sub, 'token:', token);

    this.accountId = sub;
    return Promise.resolve({
      accountId: this.accountId,
      claims: this.claims,
    });
  }
```

i use nestjs-oidc-provider package, but in the example it's not use findAccount method

this error

```
request: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/auth?client_id=186ee568-4909-4b1e-a436-f59e6978008d&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https://oidcdebugger.com/debug&scope=openid%20profile&nonce=123&state=321',
    header: {
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
      dnt: '1',
      'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
      accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
      'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.7',
      cookie: '_session=7LRnAOX9PuuzOnT77sDJG; _session.sig=QwSKCjbNhh4FmDHAUW4JCPSqbWQ; _session.legacy=7LRnAOX9PuuzOnT77sDJG; _session.legacy.sig=b6FJjirtAyIWz7ZP6WwY_M2KJ6k'
    }
  },
```

thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

Solved, with this code

```
getConfiguration(): OidcConfiguration {
    const { findAccount } = this.accountService;

    return {
      findAccount,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Your answer looks kind of okay, but I don't understand the question to begin with. It's lacking context, i.e. what you're trying to do specifically and how the problem occurs. I mean, I could not reproduce the problem myself. So, I'm not sure your question and answer will be useful to someone else having the same problem. Can you add more details?

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot to explain the details, that's because my method injected the service, then used it in the configuration function which also has a findAccount function, when i call this.accountService.findAccount it can't because the injection is in the oidcAdapter not in the oidcProvider, so I need to desctructuring it first

Comment: It is not working for me

Comment: @RakeshKumarSrivastava I quit this project haha, I'm sorry but I can help. can you send the code?